# How to make one JavaScript function, handle multiple sets of inputs, being mathematically prosessed the same way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have made this table: https://jsfiddle.net/Hougaard114/7qy70wpo/
It looks like i want it to, but it doesn't work quite like i want to. At the moment every input field has its own name, and therefor its own variable in JavaScript.

What i want is to have a Javascript function with a minimal amount of variable. What happens in each row is the same. The last row "u-værdi" spits out the result of 1/sum of"isolans"s. So i thought i could make a javascript looking like this:

```
function isolansBeregn () {
  var calc1 = document.getElementById('lambda').value;
  var calc2 = document.getElementById('tykkelse').value;
  var result = calc2/calc1;
  var numb = result;
  numb = numb.toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById('isolans').innerHTML = numb;
  var uVærdi = 1/result;
  uVærdi = uVærdi.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById('uværdi').innerHTML = uVærdi;}
```

It works, but only for the first row of inputs. Even though i give the next row the same id's, nothing happens when i type in numbers.... So now it looks like this:

HTML

```
       <table>
            <thead>
            <th colspan="4">Demo</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%" class="tdh">Materiale</td>
                    <td style="width: 30%"class="tdh">Lambda værdi (λ<sub>50</sub>)</td>
                    <td style="width: 30%"class="tdh">Tykkelse (m)</td>
                    <td style="width: 10%"class="tdh">Isolans</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yderbeklædning</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="lambda" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="tykkelse" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td id="isolans"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Isolering</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="lambda2" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="tykkelse2" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td id="isolans2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Inderbeklædning</td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="lambda3" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="tykkelse3" placeholder="Skriv her" onchange="isolansBeregn()"></td>
                    <td id="isolans3"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">U-værdi</td>
                    <td id="uværdi"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

and JavaScript

```
function isolansBeregn () {
  var calc1 = document.getElementById('lambda').value;
  var calc2 = document.getElementById('tykkelse').value;
  var calc3 = document.getElementById('lambda2').value;
  var calc4 = document.getElementById('tykkelse2').value;
  var calc5 = document.getElementById('lambda3').value;
  var calc6 = document.getElementById('tykkelse3').value;
  var result = calc2/calc1;
  var result2 = calc4/calc3;
  var result3 = calc6/calc5;
  var numb = result;
  numb = numb.toFixed(0);
  var numb2 = result2;
  numb2 = numb2.toFixed(0);
  var numb3 = result3;
  numb3 = numb3.toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById('isolans').innerHTML = numb;
  document.getElementById('isolans2').innerHTML = numb2;
  document.getElementById('isolans3').innerHTML = numb3;
  var uVærdi = 1/((result+result2)+result3);
  uVærdi = uVærdi.toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById('uværdi').innerHTML = uVærdi;}
```

It feels like overkill.

The reason this is a problem for me, is because i want the user to be able to add another row, looking exactly like the others, with a JavaScript that doesn't mind.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the fiddle into a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button), which are runnable HTML/JS/CSS (like fiddles). Currently, your question relies on off-site content (because otherwise we have no idea how you're calling your function). Off-site resources rot; questions on SO must stand alone.

Comment: your fiddle has console errors. You should edit options of Javascript and set the load type to `No wrap - in <head>`. After that, for me the fiddle works, it updates each line.

Comment: @Lulylulu: That's because the fiddle is repeating the calculation logic. (The code in the fiddle is not the same as the code above.) The OP's goal is to remove that duplication.

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood that the code above works only for the first line..

Comment: @Lulylulu thanks. Didn't know why i didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal modifications version is:

- Change the `id`s to `name`s (except for `uværdi`)
- Change your

  ```
  onchange="isolansBeregn()"
  ```

  to

  ```
  onchange="isolansBeregn(this)"
  ```

  so it passes a reference to the element on where the change occurred into the function.

Then we can work from that element what row we're in, and therefore find the other `input` elements in that row:

```
function isolansBeregn(input) {
    // Update this row
    var row = $(input).closest("tr");
    var calc1 = row.find('[name=lambda]').val();    // Probably worth converting these to number explicitly
    var calc2 = row.find('[name=tykkelse]').val();
    var result = Math.round(calc2 / calc1);         // Added rounding at the number rather than text level
    row.find('[name=isolans]').html(result).data("result", result); // ** see below

    // Get the sum of all the results
    var sum = $("[name=isolans"]).get().reduce(function(s, el) {
        return s + $(el).data("result");
    }, 0);
    var uVærdi = 1 / sum;
    uVærdi = uVærdi.toFixed(3);
    $('#uværd').html(uVærdi); // Again, perhaps .text()
}
```

Re my ** see below: We're displaying the number as text, but we'll need it as a number later, so we use jQuery's `data` feature to store it as a number as well. We *could* use the text are reparse it as a number, but I went the other way.

Explanation of `reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Note: I used jQuery because you tagged `jquery`, but your code doesn't seem to be using jQuery anywhere. The above is totally possible without jQuery as well. The only bit that's really any more work is the `.closest` part.

---

**However**, this is a good use case for *event delegation*. You can get rid of all of those `onchange=...` attributes, and instead hook `change` on the table, and then use `e.target` to know which actual `input` changed. (The `change` event doesn't bubble natively, but jQuery makes it bubble, so event delegation works with it.)

Comment: I tagged jquery because i'm open to a solution utilizing it, but perhaps i should only tag it, if it's a direct element of my question? T.J... You are the man! It Works. I apologies for all my small mistakes.. I started coding a couple of weeks ago, and i just about realised how much more you can to with JavaScript than HTML and CSS alone :)

Comment: @CasperHougaard: If you're happy to use it, tagging is the right thing, so you're good there. Glad that helped!